# PDF Download from SFMC Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Looking for the AMPScript that needs to be added to the header in order to have the document download only and not open in a browser window as using "download" in a href does not work.

```
<a href="https://website.com/somedocument.pdf" download>Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Your question is a good one, but it need rewording as it currently doesn't explain your real issue or what you have attempted nor your desired result. Judging from your comments on the answer below, you have a good query. My recommendation would be to edit your question to include more details around what you want, why and what you have tried

Comment: @Gortonington Without using the AttachFile function I was wondering with AMP script if anything can be added to force a file to download from URL. The method I'm seeking is using the download attritbute in the ahref tag but that does not work for me in SFMC so generally wanted to know if there was a workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if what you’re asking is possible, but you might consider attaching the file instead using the `AttachFile` AMPscript function:

> This function attaches the specified file to the outbound message or
> displays a link to the file when included in a landing page. This
> function returns no output.

Here’s an example of it’s usage from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/):

```
%%[

var @fileName, @fileAlias
set @fileName = "https://limedash.com/drop/LoyaltyMembers.zip"
set @fileAlias = "LoyaltyMembers.zip"

AttachFile("HTTP", @fileName, @fileAlias)

]%%
```

If you haven’t used the Attach File function in your account before, you will have to enable it first by opening a support ticket.

Comment: I think OP, wanted to create a link, which would download the file on click, rather than opening the file in a new browser tab. So here is nothing to do with `AttachFile`. That is the [scenario](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-open-in-the-browser-using-only-html/) OP wanted to fulfill but it is not working.

Comment: Thank you, my reading comprehension is just fine. Since the `download` attribute is not working in emails, I offered an alternative solution, which I pointed out in the first sentence.

Comment: Appreciate the advice and input but the main thing is these are unique monthly invoices being sent to customers so for security reasons we can not have the pdf open in a browser exposing the URL. 
I'm thinking that this is not possible without using the "AttachFile" function but appears to be a cost which I was unaware of at the moment. Has anyone used the "AttachFile" before when sending in SFMC?

Comment: Yep, using it regularly, mostly for various transactional emails. It won’t expose the url.

Comment: Do you have any info on how much it cost per email send?

Comment: You could also put it behind a login wall or otherwise secure entry to download it. Rather then an exposed public url or attachment

Comment: @desertliving480 you will have to contact your AE for the cost of sending attachments from your account

Comment: @Gortonington yes that was my original proposal but the use case is to have invoices be downloaded only as we don't have a login wall or other way of creating secure entry before these need to be emailed out.

Comment: @zuzannamj Thanks for the info and actually working with my rep right now to get a quote for the costs. Was generally curious if you could provide how you are charged based off the email sends.